# WPF DatePicker Month Name Issue

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I am having issue with DatePicker in WPF. When clicked it is showing month name cut in the height.

[image]

```
<DatePicker x:Name="dpOpening" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="32" ToolTip="Select opening date." />
```

Comment: Do you have any custom templates or styles that you could post?  I'm not sure if posting more images would help anyone.

Comment: @tencntraze I'm not customizing DatePicker style anywhere.

Comment: @tencntraze Also my ResourceDictionary.xaml is too long. How can I post it here because of character restrictions? Please help.

Comment: Do you have a high DPI setting on your computer?  Posting the entire resource dictionary would be a bit too much to sift through, is there any default style for DatePicker in there, or a control template that you're not directly setting?  @user3149813

Comment: @tencntraze : No there is no default style for datepicker. What do uou mean by a control template that you're not directly setting? I don't think I have any such. No I don't have high DPI setting also.